# C# Generic Collection resolving to wrong dll when using MVC 5 and PCL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a solution that holds a MVC 5 project and a Portable Class Library, both projects are set to target .net 4.5

The problem I am having is when using a Generic List collection proprety on a object from the PCL in my MVC Controller I get the following **error.**

> ' You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

If I resolve the `System.Collection.Generic.List` (by using F12) it takes me to two separate assemblies.

- The PCL uses

  Assembly System.Collections.dll, v4.0.0.0
- And MVC 5 uses

  Assembly mscorlib.dll, v4.0.0.0

**I am also getting the following error**:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'

I'm a bit lost with this one, and help or hints would be great

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you confused that there exist generic List<T> and plain List?

Comment: Sadly my solution isn't that simple, That I find fascinating about this issue it that it only seems to occur when I try create a Generic List using one of my models from the Portable Class Library.

I am going to try a newer version of Visual Studio. 
Thanks for the suggestion.